# CoreBluetooth: didWriteValueFor() is not called after writeValue()

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

According to Apple Developer Documentation the function didWriteValueFor() is called after the writeValue() function is called. (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral)

I have a writeable Characteristic, I looked up the property as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties/1519089-write

Now when I call the writeValue() function, the didWriteValueFor() function is never called, why? I think it's the same structure like the readValue() function which calls the didUpdateValueFor() function, which is working fine for me.
Here is my Code:

```
        func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics!{
        print(characteristic)
        if(characteristic.uuid == TX_CHARACTERISTIC){
            elsa.writeValue(dataWithHexString(hex: VALID_GET_VERSION_REQUEST), for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)//calls didWriteValueFor if Type = withResponse
        }
        if(characteristic.uuid == RX_CHARACTERISTIC){
            elsa.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)//calls didUpdateNotificationStateFor
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    guard let data = characteristic.value else { return }
    print("\nValue: \(data.toHexEncodedString()) \nwas written to Characteristic:\n\(characteristic)")
    if(error != nil){
        print("\nError while writing on Characteristic:\n\(characteristic). Error Message:")
        print(error as Any)
    }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, as far as I recall, `didWrite` is called the value is read from the characteristic, so if nothing reads, `didWrite` isn't called ... I could easily be mixing this up with another scenario, but it took me by surprise - it's kind of like if you had multiple things you wanted to write to the characteristic, `didWrite` is the APIs way of telling you can write the next value

Comment: Set a breakpoint but I suspect that your `guard` statement is returning because the value of the write characteristic will be `nil`; writing a value to a characteristic does not update its `value`.

Comment: @Paulw11 "writing a value to a characteristic does not update its value" what do you mean by that? Your suggestion was right, it gets returned at the guard but when I read the value of the characteristic afterwards, it was successfully written so how can it be nil at this point?

Comment: What I mean is performing a write on a `CBCharacteristic` instance does not update the `value` property of that instance. You must explicitly read a characteristic for the `value` property to be updated. Just because you wrote value "X" to a characteristic doesn't mean it still has that value, so you must explicitly read it to get the value.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68409316/14414215 Even w/ the value being explicitly read (using the example solution) the value is still ```null```. The funny thing is tho that there is a value returned on iOS12 and none on iOS14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paulw11 mentioned, the value is only written after it is explicitly read. I fixed this by calling a readValue() inside the didWrite() function.

Updated Solution:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    elsa.readValue(for: characteristic)
    guard let data = characteristic.value else { return }
    print("\nValue: \(data.toHexEncodedString()) \nwas written to Characteristic:\n\(characteristic)")
    if(error != nil){
        print("\nError while writing on Characteristic:\n\(characteristic). Error Message:")
        print(error as Any)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your updated solution? I am unsure what is meant.Thanks

Comment: thanks very much. I tried your solution but nothing comes back still. The value is still ```null``` even though ```didWriteValueFor``` does get called. Per chance are you using this on iOS14? I tried on iOS12 and the value is there/reported. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68409316/14414215)

Comment: @myjunk that's possible I did this in 2018, it was iOS 11 or iOS 12 back then

Comment: any chance you still have the code / access to the device etc and try w/ iOS14? If not, thanks.

Comment: @myjunk sry, I didn't continue the project since then

Answer (score 3):

When you call writeValue() you can specify if you want a response from the remote device or not. In your case you specified CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse which tells the remote device it needs to send a response back and indicate if the write was successful or not. When the remote device sends the response message this will trigger the call to didWriteValueFor(). If your device does NOT send the response then didWriteValueFor() is not called. You can read about this in the [apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral). You would need to run a bluetooth sniffer capture to confirm this, but I suspect your bluetooth device is not responding properly to the writeValue() request.

Note that each BLE characteristic has a set of properties which govern how the characteristic will behave. Some of those properties include: rear, write, write without response, notify, inform. Check the properties for the characteristic you are using and make sure it supports the 'write' property. If your characteristic supports 'write without response' but does not support 'write' then your device will not send the needed message back to your app and therefore didWriteValuefor() will not get called. Normally you can find this in the documentation, or use a bluetooth app such as "LightBlue Explorer" to view this information for your device.

Comment: That's what I was expecting too, but my BLE device is exactly doing what I send him the only thing is that didWriteValueFor() ist not called. I'm still going with the workaround to call readValue after I wrote on the Charactersitic